# A problem about the relationship between a matrix $A$ and its eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

Given a matrix $A$ and its eigenvalue $\lambda$ and its eigenvector $x$.

Problem:

From the definition that $Ax=\lambda x$, can I say that eigenvectors $x$ must be all in $A$'s column space and thus say that the rank of matrix $A$ must be not less than the number of $A$'s independent eigenvectors?

Comment: An eigenvector is in the column space if and only if the corresponding eigenvalue is nonzero, right?

Comment: @markvs thanks! I know some counter example.

Comment: What @Ted Shifrin commented is what i really want to ask!

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry , I dont know this rule and may i know that how to prove that 'An eigenvector is in the column space if and only if the corresponding eigenvalue is nonzero' is true?

Comment: Because I want to know the reason, which is something like ''If λ≠0 then x=λ−1Ax is certainly in the column space. Otherwise it is in the null space. So, no the eigenvector needn't be in the column space" that @Joshua Tilley postet on the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\lambda \ne 0$ then $x=\lambda^{-1}Ax$ is certainly in the column space. Otherwise it is in the null space. So, no the eigenvector needn't be in the column space: e.g.

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
has eigenvector
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}
with eigenvalue zero but it is not in the column space.

Since we have an independent eigenvector
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}
but the rank of the matrix is 1, we also contradict the other part.

Comment: This is what i want, thanks a lot!